# Equilibrium: Inertia & Applied Force

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light, inertia

Thank you for taking the time to read this.
I am lay and will understand if the question is closed.

My understanding is that in a vacuum, a constant force of $n$ applied to an object of mass $m$, will cause the object to accelerate. 
However, at some point (relativistic) mass increases and I assume this affects inertia and therefore reduces acceleration.

My question is: Given a certain set of values for $m$ and $n$, would inertia and the applied force ever be in equilibrium, resulting in zero acceleration (constant velocity) or does the object continue to accelerate albeit at an ever decreasing rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Sigma F = ma$.  Therefore, if a net force $n$ is applied to an object, it will accelerate.  You are correct that the acceleration will decrease, since $m$ increases, but it will never quite reach zero.

Comment: I think I understand F = ma, but ΣF=ma I do not. I get tangled in the analogy of terminal velocity, thinking that inertia acts as the analog of air resistance. Could you point me to a ref that is easily understandable for this phenomenon? Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the force is in the direction of the velocity, the [relativistic form of $F=ma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mechanics#Force) is
$$F=\gamma^3 m_o a.$$

The term *relativistic mass* has become outdated recently, but it refers to the quantity $M=\gamma m_o$, where $m_o$ is the [rest mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass).

While not necessary, we can keep this product explicit in the following rearrangement:
$$a=\frac{F}{\gamma^2 (\gamma m_o)}$$

The denominator goes to infinity as speed $v$ approaches $c$. (This is because $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.) 
So it appears that the acceleration decreases as speed increases, and in the limit of $v\rightarrow c$, $a\rightarrow 0$. But since this limit can never actually be reached, I would say that acceleration is always non-zero for any physical object.

Other assumptions used: There is only one force acting on the object, denoted $F$.